# Ubuntu Studio upgrade fails

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-studio

I'm trying to upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04

I looked at /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log and I can see problems around these lines, but aren't sure what to do:

```
2021-05-13 20:07:50,142 DEBUG Marking 'ubuntustudio-desktop' for upgrade
2021-05-13 20:07:50,287 DEBUG blacklist expr 'ubuntustudio-desktop' matches 'ubuntustudio-desktop-core'
2021-05-13 20:07:50,287 DEBUG The package 'ubuntustudio-desktop-core' is marked for removal but it's in the removal blacklist
2021-05-13 20:07:50,293 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'ubuntustudio-desktop-core' is marked for removal but it is in the removal blacklist.'
2021-05-13 20:07:50,293 DEBUG abort called
```

Is there a work-around for this or a way to discover an underlying problem?

Comment: No: That message suggests a critical failure in YOUR choice of packages. Something you have installed conflicts with Ubuntu Studio. It does not indicate a failure by Ubuntu Studio.

Comment: Ok, great, do you have any suggestions about how I might discover what the conflict might be?

Comment: There's likely a lot more information in your apt log, or in the specific error message you refer to. It must be something you deliberately installed, and it's likely to be something that's not in the Ubuntu repositories. If you still cannot figure it out, install Synaptic or Aptitude, which will filter broken packages ("broken" =  "conflicting") for you.

Comment: /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log starts with 
````
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
```